# Google Cloud SQL ER_HOST_IS_BLOCKED

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine, cloud-sql-proxy

i'm getting some issues connecting to Cloud SQL from Container engine...

I followed https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/container-engine-connect tutorial and it all seems to work, though I had to tweak a few things with the password/user stuff being sent.

However after several failed attempts of the container trying connect using Cloud SQL Proxy I am now seeing this error `ER_HOST_IS_BLOCKED: Host '104.197.135.204' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'`

`FLUSH HOSTS;` doesn't seem to fix it.
and I'm unable to change the `max_connect_errors` value since root doesn't have the `super` privilege & it's not part of the MySQL flags customizable https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Got some answers through Google Cloud SQL Slack channel. It was actually related to a different database

However, I did learn that the `ER_HOST_IS_BLOCKED` is reset whenever a successful connection is made so this should never be an issue